# How to multiply index values looped in a list

Tags: python

I get this error when I run my code however I had converted the data in my list to an int
I have been working on this for weeks and cannot figure it out
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '95.7'
How can I by pass this error to get the total ,

```
import csv
counter = 0
sum = 0
avg = 0
with open('sales_data_sample (3).csv','r') as csv_file: # opens the csv 
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader) # skips the header so we can work only with raw data
    for  ((lines)) in csv_reader: # loop through all data in the file
        counter =+ 1 # counter
        lines[1] = int(lines[1])
        lines[2] = int(lines[2])
        avg = avg + (lines[1]* lines[2])
    total = avg/counter
```

Comment: You can't convert a str containing a float directly to an integer. Either convert the string representation to an integer before passing it to `int()` or convert it using `float()` first, then `int()`. But in this case, do you really want to use integers and not floats? Furthermore, `sum` is a built-in function, so don't use that as a variable name.

Comment: Use `float` instead of `int`. Replace `int(lines[1])` by `float(lines[1])`, same for `lines[2]`

Comment: It seems your data is string. So convert it float then it using `int(float(lines[1]))` and `int(float(lines[2]))`

Comment: Is there some reason this has to be an integer?  Seems like `float()` would work.

Comment: @aberry That's literally what the code is already doing...

Comment: @JohnGordon you are right why to loose decimal part. it should be `float` only.
Sorry I missed `float` , edited now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the data maybe somewhere in your data you have 95.7 and since you are converting it into int so that's why it is breaking your code. You should try

```
lines[1] = int(float(lines[1]))
lines[2] = int(float(lines[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're using integers (whole numbers). Either your lines in the csv are not whole numbers, or when calculating `total`, you are dividing into decimals.

To solve this, you have to use a floating-point number. Replace your uses of integers with floats.

eg.
`lines[1] = int(lines[1])` should become `lines[1] = float(lines[1])`

You will however find you start getting numbers with long decimal places, so you can round them with the `round()` function, like this:

`lines[1] = round(float(lines[1]), '.2f')` Which will set it to 2 decimal places. You can change that 2 to any number of decimal places you'd like.

```py
lines[1] = round(float(lines[1]), '.2f')
lines[2] = round(float(lines[2]), '.2f')
```

Comment: Recommending to use `Decimal` for exact representation and then applying `round` to two decimals' precision, really...?